# Use DateTimeFormatterBuilder for parsing dates of missing day and default to end of month

Tags: java, localdate

I need to parse dates in various formats. Some of these are missing the "day". Now I want to default to end of month. I am not sure if there is a direct way where we can default to end of month

```
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("MM.yyyy")
        .parseDefaulting(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1) // can we default to end of month?
        .toFormatter();

LocalDate.parse("11.2017", f)
```

But if not, how can I know that the original date was missing the day (or that a default was used) and therefore I need to adjust it manually by using `LocalDate.parse("11.2017", f).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
      .appendPattern("MM.yyyy")
      .parseDefaulting(DAY_OF_MONTH, 31) // set 31
      .toFormatter();
```

Just set `DAY_OF_MONTH` with `31`, `DAY_OF_MONTH` will base on `rangeUnit` to choose the **last day** of **parse month**.

```
/**
 * The day-of-month.
 * <p>
 * This represents the concept of the day within the month.
 * In the default ISO calendar system, this has values from 1 to 31 in most months.
 * April, June, September, November have days from 1 to 30, while February has days
 * from 1 to 28, or 29 in a leap year.
 * <p>
 * Non-ISO calendar systems should implement this field using the most recognized
 * day-of-month values for users of the calendar system.
 * Normally, this is a count of days from 1 to the length of the month.
 */
DAY_OF_MONTH("DayOfMonth", DAYS, MONTHS, ValueRange.of(1, 28, 31), "day"),
```

Example:

```
LocalDate parse = LocalDate.parse("02.2017", f);
System.out.println(parse.getDayOfMonth());
```

Output:

> 28